# Sending json from one Rails app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is simple here. I want to send json data from one Rails app to other Rails app via `POST`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete architectural example of how to do this with ActiveResource [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sF-m3P-Mrm8)
If you just need a simple call, I'd suggest to use [REST-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) for the calling side.

The provider side is pretty standard. Just expose an action that responds to JSON posts. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have one Rails app accept JSON via a POST action in a controller, and have the other Rails app submit the JSON via an HTTP library like [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).